# Scheme -- Returning a recursively created list

Tags: list, recursion, return

```
(define (de-caesar shift numbers ret)
(cond
[(null? numbers) ret]
[else (de-caesar shift (cdr numbers) (append ret (list(+ (car numbers) shift))))] 
))
```

This function takes a value (3) and a list of values '(17 3 9 21) and an empty list '() as parameters.
Recursively, a new list of values is formed and returned '(20 6 12 24) by shifting all of the input values by 3.

That being said, I am supposed to be able to do this with a function that only accepts 2 parameters (shift and numbers).

How can I return this list of new values, without passing around a pre-created empty list parameter?

Any help/information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By making a function that calls this one as helper with the right initial arguments. Optionally you can move this inside it so it is unavailable outside. Optionally you can blend calling by making it a named let.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I'm new to racket, and so far I hate it. That being said, I don't know how to do any of what you said -- can you please elaborate.